# Stacking with custom classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I want to build a stacking classifier for the three label following dataset:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# Define dataset
def get_dataset():
    X, y = make_classification(
        n_samples=1000,
        n_features=20,
        n_informative=15,
        n_redundant=5,
        random_state=2022,
        n_classes=3,
    )
    return X, y
```

I want to use `sklearn` models plus a dummy model of my own:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_X_y, check_array, check_is_fitted
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels


class DummyClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        if y is None:
            raise ValueError("requires y to be passed, but the target y is None")

        X, y = check_X_y(X, y)

        self.n_features_in_ = X.shape[1]
        self.classes_ = np.unique(y)
        self.is_fitted_ = True

        self.X_ = X
        self.y_ = y

        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        check_is_fitted(self, ["is_fitted_", "X_", "y_"])
        X = check_array(X)

        return self.y_[np.ones(X.shape[0], dtype=np.int64)]

    def is_classifier():
        return True
```

combined:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier

def get_stacking():
    # Base models
    level0 = list()
    level0.append(("logistic reg", LogisticRegression()))
    level0.append(("knn", KNeighborsClassifier()))
    level0.append(("cart", DecisionTreeClassifier()))
    level0.append(("svm", SVC()))
    level0.append(("random", DummyClassifier()))
    # Meta learner
    level1 = LogisticRegression()
    # Stacking ensemble
    model = StackingClassifier(estimators=level0, final_estimator=level1, cv=5)
    return model
```

I get interpretability through the `final_estimator`'s coefficients:

```
stack = get_stacking()
stack.fit(X, y)
for i in range(3):
    print(stack.final_estimator_.classes_[i])
    print(stack.final_estimator_.coef_[i])
```

I understand that for 3 classes and 4 models, I get 12 coefficients for each final output class. In my case I have 5 models but 13 coefficients:

```
0
[ 0.12169113 -0.00882275 -0.10934588  1.39370271 -0.647395   -0.7427852
  0.28413927  0.05880896 -0.33942572  0.17350847 -0.71793331 -0.62128377
 -0.01146239]
1
[ 0.05118664  0.07307435 -0.12623659 -0.7132075   1.22529472 -0.51406282
 -0.16767687 -0.00635399  0.17205527 -0.27319447  0.6866465  -0.47218785
  0.09065114]
2
[-0.17287777 -0.06425161  0.23558246 -0.68049521 -0.57789973  1.25684802
 -0.1164624  -0.05245497  0.16737045  0.099686    0.03128681  1.09347161
 -0.07918875]
```

Where's the problem with my `DummyClassifier`?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html) of `StackingClassifier`, the parameter `stack_method` is set to 'auto' by default, which will try to call `predict_proba`, `decision_function`, and `predict` in that order. The first three classifiers in the ensemble (`LogisticRegression`, `KNeighborsClassifier`, and `DecisionTreeClassifier`) have a `predict_proba` method defined, which returns an array of shape `(n, c)` where `n` are the number of rows from the input array and `c` are the number of classes. For example, predicting with the `LogisticRegression` model (the first model in the list of estimators):

```
stack.estimators_[0].predict_proba(np.ones((5, 20)))
```

Will return an array of shape `(5, 3)` since there are 5 rows in the input array and 3 classes in your example.

The fourth classifier in the ensemble, `SVC` does not define `predict_proba` but it does define `decision_function`, the next in the precedence in order, which also returns an array of shape `(n, c)`.

The `DummyClassifier` you have defined only defines `predict`, the last in the precedence order, and it returns an array of shape `(1,)`. When this is concatenated with the other outputs, there will be 4 x 3 + 1 = 13 coefficients, as you're observing.  To have 5 x 3 = 15 coefficients, corresponding to 3 outputs per model, the `DummyClassifier` needs to either change the output of `predict`, or define a `predict_proba` or `decision_function` method. I would recommend doing the latter for consistency, as the `predict` method in the other models returns predictions in the same format. A simple way to do that would be defining `predict_proba` which just one-hot encodes the output from the `predict` method:

```
    def predict_proba(self, X):
        prediction = self.predict(X)
        output = np.zeros((X.shape[0], self.classes_.size))
        output[np.arange(X.shape[0]), prediction] = 1
        return output
```

After defining this method in the `DummyClassifier`, there are 15 output coefficients as expected:

```
0
[ 0.09247372 -0.01868337 -0.07385955  1.42720504 -0.64726132 -0.78001291
  0.32688202  0.00670499 -0.3336562   0.15328638 -0.7135016  -0.6332385
 -0.00235729  0.          0.0022881 ]
1
[ 0.02883837  0.0887803  -0.11983384 -0.74669545  1.23962866 -0.49514838
 -0.07969914 -0.0489527   0.12643667 -0.26378726  0.69218343 -0.46387066
 -0.09017733  0.          0.08796216]
2
[-0.12131209 -0.07009693  0.19369339 -0.6805096  -0.59236733  1.27516129
 -0.24718288  0.04224771  0.20721954  0.11050088  0.02131817  1.09710915
  0.09253462  0.         -0.09025026]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dummy classifier is returning integer-encoded values rather than one-hot encoded values, so it is only adding a single dimension to your final estimator's input.